# Reflexive and non-reflexive transitive closures

Tags: logic, alloy

What are the **reflexive** and **non-reflexive transitive closures** in Alloy and how do they differ in Alloy?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

The **non-reflexive transitive closure** operator is `^`. `foo.^bar` is the **non-reflexive transitive closure** of `foo` with respect to `bar`. This will return the set of all things you could produce by applying `.bar` to `foo` *one or more times*. For example, `foo.^bar` is equal to the union of the following expressions:

```
    foo.bar
    foo.bar.bar
    foo.bar.bar.bar
    foo.bar.bar.bar.bar 
    ...
```

This list is infinite.

The **reflexive transitive closure** operator is `*`. `foo.*bar` is the **reflexive transitive closure** of `foo` with respect to `bar`. This will return the set of all things you could produce by applying `.bar` to `foo` *zero or more times*. For example, `foo.*bar` is equal to the union of the following expressions:

```
    foo
    foo.bar
    foo.bar.bar
    foo.bar.bar.bar
    ...
```

This list is also infinite. This is equivalent to `foo + foo.^bar`

Answer (score 0):

Both `transitive closure` (`^`) and `reflexive transitive closure` (`*`) are **unary operators** which may only be applied to an operand which is a **binary relation**.

Transitive closure of a binary relation `bar` is a binary relation defined as

```
^bar = bar + bar.bar + bar.bar.bar + ...
```

Reflexive transitive closure of a binary relation `bar` is a binary relation defined as

```
*bar = iden + ^bar
```

where `iden` is the identity binary relation.

The most common usage pattern of the two transitive closure operators is when it is preceded by a relational join, like in the example provided by [@LEJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5931164/lej): `foo.^bar` and `foo.*bar`.  It is worth noting that there is no magic in `.^` and `.*`: the dot operator (`.`) is the same old relational join, and the `^` and `*` operators are the closure operators as defined above.  So if you work out the equations, you will arrive at the same expressions for `foo.^bar` and `foo.*bar` that [@LEJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5931164/lej) already provided:

```
foo.^bar = foo.(^bar) = foo.(bar + bar.bar + ...) = foo.bar + foo.bar.bar + ...
foo.*bar = foo.(*bar) = foo.(iden + bar + bar.bar + ...) = foo + foo.bar + foo.bar.bar + ...
```